# How to search influxdb by tag = list of values?

Tags: search, tags, influxdb

I have an influxdb test data set look like this:

tag: user. values can be user1, user2, ... user1000;

field: value. values can be random between 0 and 100.

let's say I have 1,000 users, and 500 belong to group 1 and the rest belong to group 2. if I want to do something like this: select count(value) from  where user in list of (user1, user2, ... user 500), how can I efficiently do this?

Comment: Do you have the groups defined at all ? IS the Group also a tag ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Regular Expressions](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#regular-expressions) , aka "regex".

In your case, this is an awkward way to do it, but should get you close. A more elegant and maintainable version is left as an exercise.   :)

We have to be careful that we correctly match e.g. `user61` but not `user610`, so we need separate search terms for single-digit user ids, two-digit ids, etc. `$` means "end of line", in this case the end of the tag value.

```
SELECT count(value) from my_measurement WHERE 
  (user =~ /user[0-9]$/ OR            -- this matches user0 to user9
   user =~ /user[0-9][0-9]$/ OR       -- user10 to user99
   user =~ /user[1-4][0-9][0-9]$/ OR  -- user100 to user499
   user = 'user500')
  GROUP BY user
```